# Unable to get File Listing from Apache Commons net Implementation

Tags: java, ftps

**SMALL UPDATE:**
If it does connect further I get (continued debug info):

```
200 PROT P OK, data channel will be secured.
CCC
200 CCC Context Enabled.
PASV
Exception:Could not parse response code.
Server Reply: ': command not understood.
```

I am working on a project of which I have no control over the server.
It needs to be an explicit SSL connection and use a Clear Command Channel.
It gets to the execCCC command and then just stalls,

```
FTPSClient pftps = new FTPSClient(false);
pftps.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(System.out));
pftps.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(300);
try {
    pftps.setAuthValue("SSL");
    pftps.setUseEPSVwithIPv4(true);
    pftps.connect(result.getPershingHost(), 21);
    pftps.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    pftps.user(result.getPershingLoginId());
    pftps.pass(result.getPershingLoginPass());
    pftps.execPBSZ(0L);
    pftps.execPROT("P");
    pftps.execCCC();
    FTPFile[] files = pftps.listFiles();
    for (FTPFile file : files) {
        System.out.println(file);
    }
...
```

Debug:

```
AUTH SSL
234 AUTH TLS-P/SSL OK.
USER myuser
331 Password required for myuser.
PASS password
230 Connect:Enterprise UNIX login ok, access restrictions apply.
PBSZ 0
200 PBSZ 0 OK.
PROT P
200 PROT P OK, data channel will be secured.
CCC
200 CCC Context Enabled.
```

A few times I get an error like an error parsing the SYST command response but 9/10 times, it's just stalled here.
I am using commons-net 3.3, which I thought fixed the previous errors regarding using CCC.
Also, to note, I have tried to put the execCCC before the PROT/PBSZ and it hangs even then on the CCC command.
I would appreciate any help as this is bugging the hell out of me.

Comment: Have yout tried port `22` instead `21`? since it is `sftp`

Comment: It is actually FTPS that uses explicit SSL. This connects on port 21.